# Python error on sqlite3 import

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm newbie to Python. I want to import sqlite3 in my script. Everything works correctly until I move my script to another subfolder.

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
```

If I create this script in `C://Python34` it's ok. But if I move it to `C://Python34/test` it fails to import sqlite3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\test\sqlite3.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "C:\Python34\test\sqlite3.py", line 5, in <module>
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

So, how to import sqlite lib properly to make it work in any subdir?

Comment: Did you name your script `sqlite3.py` and you are trying to use the `sqlite3` package?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you, now it works fine since I've renamed my script.